# Is there a unique session ID for a primary tab in Service Console?

Tags: service-cloud-console, session, id, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I am trying to implement an account verification module and there are requirements to not verify a customer when they are reopened under the same primary tab (and they have already been verified).

I have implemented the console toolkit and can see there are functions to get the Primary Tab Id but this id does not seem to be in a format that is unique so I am hesitant to use this as the filter in any query I run as I may pull the same id twice...

Is there such a thing as a session id for each primary tab? Some unique way of identifying that you are within the same tab and reopening the same record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab IDs are unique within a console, but not guaranteed to be the same if you close and reopen a tab or if you leave and re-enter the console.

So you may have primary 'scc-pt-0' with a subtab 'scc-st-0' and 'scc-st-1'. If you close that primary tab then reopen it then it's possible it will now be 'scc-pt-1'. But if you leave the primary tab open it will always be 'scc-pt-0' until you leave the console.

From the doc here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm

> IDs are only valid during a user session; IDs become invalid when the user leaves the Salesforce console.

Depending on your exact requirements you may be able to use the openSubtab and openPrimaryTab methods and use the optional 'name' parameter to give it a kind of unique ID that you track yourself.